# Crontab - Python Script Runs, sends output to mail, but doesn't write to file

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x, cron, ubuntu-14.04

I have a job that I have set to run every 5 minutes. I confirm that it indeed runs by running:

```
grep CRON /var/log/syslog
```

It shows that it is running the exact command I need it to run 'python3 /root/foofolder/foo.py R'

```
Dec 29 23:05:01 fooserver CRON[9306]: (root) CMD (python3 /root/foofolder/foo.py R)
```

It sends the output to mail. I read the mail and output looks as if I was running it in terminal, exactly as I need. The script is supposed to write out to a file. It fails to do so. Running the script in the command line writes the file just fine. I've given the .py file +x permissions and added

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to the beginning of the .py script. Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: You did not specify if you are using absolute or relative paths for your file. Use absolute paths, always.

Comment: Without showing the gist of the `foo.py` script, you make it essentially impossible for us to debug it.

Comment: unrelated: you don't need +x permission and/or the shebang (`#!`) in this case because you use `python3`. You could omit `python3` if you set the correct shebang `#!/usr/bin/python3` and the executable permisions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using absolute paths and/or `os.chdir` to a well-known location early in your script (before opening the file).

Comment: setting the path using os.chdir worked like a charm.

Comment: Happy it worked! Please consider accepting this answer. Thanks!